# How to restore influxdb from local backup || InfluxDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, influxdb

I am trying to import client's provided influx db data backup to my local influx db. But getting following error.

ENV: Ubuntu

Influx DB service is already running.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzEAQ.png)

Trying to restore influx db backup.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using the wrong command to execute influxdb task. It should be `influxd` instead of `influx`. Please follow the steps below to restore your database.

1. Check your data-dir path by executing: `influxd config`. Copy the data-dir section.
2. See database name by executing: `SHOW Databases`
3. Execute to restore: `influxd restore -database {database_name} -data-dir {your_data_dir_path} /path/to/your/backup`